# execl do not leave from child

Tags: c, fork

I have a program that reads a file, treat it and put the results in an output file. When I have an argument (input file), I create the output file and write it the content.

I've made a fork() in order to redirect the stdout a write() content.

```
char *program;

program = malloc(80);

sprintf(program, "./program < %s > %s", inputFile, outputFile);   
int st;
switch (fork()) {
  case -1:
       error("fork error");
         case 0:
           /* I close the stdout */
           close (1);

             if (( fd = open(outputfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP)==-1)){

                 error("error creating the file \n");
                 exit(1);
             }

             execlp("./program", program,  (char *)0);

             error("Error executing program\n");
              default:
          // parent process - waits for child's end and ends
            wait(&st);
            exit(0);
     //*****************

              }
```

The child is created properly with the < > stdin and stdout files are created.
But, the child never ends, and when I kill the father, the output file is empty, so the code did not executed.

What is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: I would do this with `open()` and `dup2()` and `exec()` rather than trying to use `<` and `>` for IO redirection.

Comment: Thanks! both solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The functions in the exec family don't understand redirections**.

The way you're calling `execlp`, you're passing one argument to your program: `./program < %s > %s`. That's right, one argument. Of course, `execlp` doesn't know what redirections are, and neither does `program`.

I would replace all your code with:

```
char *program = malloc(LEN);

snprintf(program, LEN, "./program < %s > %s", inputFile, outputFile);  
system(program);
```

Comment: I agree with your diagnosis, but I'm not sold on the proposed solution - dup2 seems like a far cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: @awoodland Why cleaner ? Leaving redirection to the shell is probably easiest - it's what the shell's for. Of course it's not as efficient and not as portable but it's made of 3 lines.

Comment: Nesting shell stuff deep inside C feels dirty. Aside from the non-graceful failure with funky shells (I'd rather have a compile time error than a weird runtime problem if it's going to fail) it's prone to evil things, for example if outputFile has a `somepath; rm -rf ~` in it, or worse.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with system() but the program still keep waiting.... do not return.

Comment: @awoodland Yes, security is always and issue. Well, I guess it's up to the op.